# how to get id of newly inserted rows using openxml?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a XML block which I want to insert into database. database contains 3 tables namely `itemMapping`, `links` and `category`. `Links` table will have only link from XML, `category` table will have `category` from XML.

```
<item>
<link>http://google.com</link>

<category>search engine</category>
<category>android</category>
<category>gmail</category>
</item>
```

Here come my confusion, 'itemMaping' table contains following columns :

`ID`, `LinkID`, `CategoryID`

In `itemMapping` table I have to insert linkID and categoryID of newly inserted rows. So according to sample XML `itemMapping` table will have 3 records for each category, but to insert record in this table i will need `linkID` and `categoryID` from above. How I can achieve this? I want to do this in single SP if possible.

Comment: Look into the OUTPUT clause. If you insert the links and categories after extracting them from the XML, and those tables have identity columns, you should be able to retrieve the new identity values.

Comment: What version of SQL Server do you use? From SQL Server 2005 you can use the [output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause **and** you can use the [xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187339) data type instead of openxml.

Comment: i am using sql server 2008 express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Consider the following tables:

```
Country Table
CountryID CountryName LastEditUser

Province table
ProvinceID ProvinceName CountryID LastEditUser
```

Consider CountryID and ProvinceID were identity columns.

IN SQL YOU can insert records to these two tables using a single stored procedure take a look at the quick example

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertProvince
(
@ProvinceName VARCHAR(128),
@CountryName VARCHAR(128),
@LastEditUser VARCHAR(128)
)
AS
    DECLARE @CountryID INT

    INSERT INTO Country
    (CountryName, LastEditUser)
    VALUES
    (@CountryName, @LastEditUser)

    @CountryID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    INSERT INTO Province
    (ProvinceName, CountryID, LastEditUser)
    VALUES
    (@ProvinceName, @CountryID, @LastEditUser)
END
```

SQL Server has a function called [scope_identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx), it returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in the same scope. A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger, function, or batch. Therefore, two statements are in the same scope if they are in the same stored procedure, function, or batch.

Comment: thanks for the example but my problem is little different. In my case, a single link can have 5 or 15 category and I have to insert those 5 or 15 category IDs in itemMapping table. As far as I know `scope_identity` will return last inserted row ID but how i will get IDs for 5 or 5 inserted rows?

Comment: @RAJK this logic is applicable already buddy, you just have to create a cursor that would loop for each of those ids then insert a mapping. you can also use batch insert statements if you dont feel like using cursors if the problem is quite resolvable by using a batch insert i prefer it more. Though not all situations can be resolve using Batch inserts.

Answer (score 0):

Insert into `Links` and capture the `LinkID` with `scope_identity()` to a variable. Insert into `Category` and capture the generated ID's in a table variable. Use that table variable as source for the insert to `ItemMapping`.

Assuming your tables look like this.

```
create table Category
(
  CategoryID int identity primary key,
  Name varchar(50)
)

create table Links
(
  LinkID int primary key identity,
  Link varchar(50)
)

create table ItemMapping
(
  LinkID int references Links(LinkID),
  CategoryID int references Category(CategoryID),
  primary key(LinkID, CategoryID)
)
```

You can do like this using an XML variable `@XML`.

```
declare @IDs table(ID int)
declare @LinkID int

insert into Links(Link)
select T.X.value('.', 'nvarchar(50)')
from @XML.nodes('item/link') as T(X) 

set @LinkID = scope_identity()

insert into Category(Name)
output inserted.CategoryID into @IDs
select T.X.value('.', 'nvarchar(50)')
from @XML.nodes('item/category') as T(X) 

insert into ItemMapping(LinkID, CategoryID)
select @LinkID, I.ID
from @IDs as I
```

[SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/71774)